# GridView in widget is loading infinitely

Tags: android, gridview, widget

I want to show images on my widget in gridview. Currently I have tree elements and I only see this loading images infinitely. What might be the reason?

[image: gridview on widget loading]

Here is my code.

```
@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

    ...
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(),R.layout.plant_widget);
    int imgRes = PlantUtils.getPlantImageRes(mContext,
            currentTime - createdAt, currentTime - wateredAt, plantType);
    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_plant_image, imgRes);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_plant_name, Long.toString(plantId));

    return views;
}

private static RemoteViews getGardenGridRemoteView(Context context, int imgRes, long plantId, boolean showWater)
{
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_grid_view);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, GridWidgetService.class);
    views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.gv_widget_plant, intent);
    Intent appIntent = new Intent(context, PlantDetailActivity.class);
    PendingIntent appPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context, 0, appIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.gv_widget_plant, appPendingIntent);

    views.setEmptyView(R.id.gv_widget_plant, R.id.empty_view);

    return views;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by making sure `getViewTypeCount()` in your RemoteViewsFactory class returns a non-zero value. The below should do the trick:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1; // if this is 0, then loading will be "perpetual"
}
```